# Filter & Order my SharePoint list using index columns is raising error "Attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, power-automate, list-view-threshold

I have this GetItems action inside my Power automate flow:-

[image]

the SharePoint list contain around 140,000 items. and all the fields that are involved in the above Filter and OrderBY are already added to the lists indexes 4 months ago.

so why i am getting this error :-

[image]

Here are my fields types:-

- FY is a choice column
- Design Period is a choice column
- DesignTypeOrder is a Number
- HealinesReferecne is a Single line of text
- DientionOrder is a Number
- LangaugeOrder  is a Number

any advice? why i am getting threshold error on a query that include index columns?

Comment: I believe you can't get more then 5000 items even when columns are indexed

Comment: The **first** condition in your filter query should return less than 5000 items (even when the related column is indexed), then only your filter query will work. So, try adding the condition which will return less number of items at the start for filter query. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: @Danny no get items can get up to 100,000 items using pagination settings

Comment: @GaneshSanap-MVP the wired thing is that my first filter which is based on the FY column return only 74 items... so not sure why i am getting threshold error

Comment: Try removing Order By query to narrow down the issue and see if it works to get the list items.